# Getting Last Id from a Cross Server Insert using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a cross server insert

```
INSERT INTO server.database.dbo.table (Field) VALUES('test')
```

Afterward, I need to get the id of the last insert. However, when I run the the scope_identity function, I don't get the latest id from the foreign server.

```
SELECT @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

How would I retrieve the last id from a cross server insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

> The scope of the @@IDENTITY function
>   is current session on the local server
>   on which it is executed. This function
>   cannot be applied to remote or linked
>   servers. To obtain an identity value
>   on a different server, execute a
>   stored procedure on that remote or
>   linked server and have that stored
>   procedure (which is executing in the
>   context of the remote or linked
>   server) gather the identity value and
>   return it to the calling connection on
>   the local server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're going to have to wrap the INSERT in a stored procedure on the remote linked server and have the stored procedure return the IDENTITY column value.

reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx