# SQL Server identity issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, identity

I have a query like below

```
declare @str_CustomerID int
Insert into IMDECONP38.[Customer].dbo.CustomerMaster
( CustomerName , CustomerAddress , CustomerEmail , CustomerPhone )
values ( ‘werw12e’ , ‘jkj12kj’ , ‘3212423sdf’ , ‘1212121′
)

select @str_CustomerID= scope_identity()
```

After execution it returns null in my parameter.

I want to get the value of identity. How can I do that?

The main issue over here is "IMDECONP38" - the server name that I used. If I remove this I can get the value of identity in my parameter.

Comment: what do you mean "parameter" in this context?

Comment: There actually is an identity column in the table, right?  Silly question, but just in case . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use "IMDECONP38" then you break SCOPE_IDENTITY because

- the INSERT scope is now on the IMDECONP38 linked server
- SCOPE_IDENTITY runs on the local server, not IMDECONP38

If on SQL Server 2005, try the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28SQL.90%29.aspx) clause but I'm not sure how it works for a linked server call

```
Insert into IMDECONP38.[Customer].dbo.CustomerMaster
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID   --change as needed
( CustomerName , CustomerAddress , CustomerEmail , CustomerPhone )
values ( ‘werw12e’ , ‘jkj12kj’ , ‘3212423sdf’ , ‘1212121′
)
```

Edit: Prutswonder said it first: use a stored proc on the linked server

Comment: Sql server giving error :

Remote tables are not allowed to be the target of a DML statement with an OUTPUT clause, or the target of the INTO clause.

Answer (score 9):

See [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827118/getting-last-id-from-a-cross-server-insert-using-sql-server) for a similar problem: You cannot retrieve a scoped variable like `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from another server. Instead, you should use a stored procedure on the remote server to achieve this.

Comment: Good call. Best advice so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use a stored procedure in the remote database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCustomer (@name varchar(100), @address varchar(100), 
    @email varchar(100), @phone varchar(100), @id int OUT)
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerMaster 
    (CustomerName , CustomerAddress , CustomerEmail , CustomerPhone ) 
    VALUES (@name, @address, @email, @phone)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
GO

DECLARE @id int
EXEC IMDECONP38.Customer.dbo.InsertCustomer 'Fred','Bedrock','a@b','5',@id OUT
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For sql server 2012, to get the name of the identity column

```
select col_name(sys.all_objects.object_id, column_id) as id from    sys.identity_columns 
join sys.all_objects on sys.identity_columns.object_id = sys.all_objects.object_id
where sys.all_objects.object_id = object_id('system_files')
```

If you have a Linked server you can use this:

```
select iden.name as id 
from [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].sys.identity_columns as iden
join [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].sys.all_objects allobj
    on iden.object_id = allobj.object_id
where allobj.name = 'TABLE NAME HERE'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select @@IDENTITY AS 'variablename'
```

Comment: using `@@IDENTITY` is dangerous because it returns the last
ID generated from any scope.

Comment: I've never wanted to upvote a comment multiple times until now.

Answer (score -2):

Please check if there are any **triggers** set for your table. This will cause a problem when you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last inserted identity field.

HTH

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON does not affect SCOPE_IDENTITY. Or do you have an MSDN reference to back this up. As my question notes, only DataAdaptors can be affected by SET NOCOUNT ON here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage

Comment: @gbn: I had this same problem and SET NoCount OFF did the trick for me. Anyways I have taken that out of my answer :-).

Comment: Triggers affect the value of @@Identity not scope_identity()