# T-SQL OPENQUERY to MySQL - Insert ID

Tags: mysql, sql-server, openquery

I am using OPENQUERY to do an insert from MSSQL 2005 to MySQL. How do I get at the last inserted id on the MySQL db back into my MSSQL procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the following work around i can able to solve my problem
Following function to get identity value

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetIdentity (   @tablename varchar(50) ) 
RETURNS varchar(50) 
AS 
BEGIN   
-- Return the result of the function    
RETURN (select cast(IDENT_CURRENT(@tablename) as varchar(50))) 
END 
GO


SELECT id FROM OPENQUERY(IMDECONP38, 'select Customer.dbo.GetIdentity (''CustomerMaster'') as id')
```

related question : [SQL Server identity issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621887/sql-server-identity-issue)

Comment: The first openqury would do the insert, and would another second openquery command call this function? And if so, would the scope still be ok?

Comment: no its out of scope because its querying data from remote server. Thats y i created this function in remote server database to get identity value